# Match Variadic Function - Vim Regex

Tags: c, regex, vim

Suppose you have the following C function:

```c
void foo(int a, int b, const char* fmt, ...)
```

and you wanted to find/replace function calls of `foo()` with `bar()`

```c
void bar(int a, int b, int c, const char* fmt, ...)
```

How would you match calls of `foo()` with capture groups around `a`, `b`, `fmt` as well as the variadic arguments `...`?

I would also like the solution to not depend on the data type of the parameters at all if possible.

My current attempt is: `foo(\(.*\),\s*\n*\s*\(.*\),\s*\n*\s*\(.*\),\s*\n*\s*\(.*\));`

But it breaks as the final `\(.*\)` doesn't match newlines with the wildcard character.

Comment: If the only problem is that `\(.*\)` does not match newlines, replace it with `\(\_.\{-}\)`

Comment: You should give more context for this question. If it is for a one-time project change, it is generally not worthwhile to construct an elaborate solution; just go through the project and manually edit all uses of `foo`. If it needs to be done repeatedly (why?), you cannot do it with regular expressions properly, because they cannot match all the possibilities of C grammar (such as arguments with internal parentheses and commas). A preprocessor macro might be able to do the job; you could use `#define foo(a, b, ...) bar((a), (b), c, __VA_ARGS__)`.

Comment: In general, handling all the possible variants is pretty damn tricky: `foo(hangup(12+catz, 15/dogz), window_size(scr, subwin), "foo(a, b, fmt, arg1, 'd')", atan2(dogz, sqrt(b * b + c * c)))` or anything similar is going to give you a screaming fit if you try to do it with regexes.  I haven't even tried to embed comments into the call.

Answer (score 1):

Best solution: use an actual refactoring tool.

Best time/effort compromise in Vim:

1. Search your whole project for `foo()` calls with something like:

   ```
   :grep -r foo\( **/*.{c,h}
   ```

   This populates the quickfix list with entries for each line where there is an occurrence of `foo(` in the given files.
2. substitute `foo` with `bar` on each match, with confirmation:

   ```
   :cdo s/foo(/bar(/gc
   ```

   This runs the substitution on every entry in the quickfix list and thus on every line where there is an occurrence of `foo(`. With the `/c` flag, you get a prompt asking you to confirm the substitution. It is a bit pedestrian but:

   - it puts you in control of the refactoring,
   - it also works on comments,
   - it doesn't require too much regexp work upfront, ie: you would be finished by now.